# realloc causes memory leak according to valgrind

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, realloc

I've implemented a method to reallocate an array field of a struct. 
Valgrind shouts that this causes mem-leak.

> 122,689,764 (2,569,440 direct, 120,120,324 indirect) bytes in 4,146 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 39 of 40

Here is my method. 
Any thought about why this might happen? 
I made sure I free the `nodeToReallocate->childPtrTable` at the end. 
And anyway in this case I guess valgrind would indicate the initial malloc as the problem, right?

```
void reallocatePtrTable(mmUctNode* nodeToReallocate){
    if(nodeToReallocate->ptrRowIndex<nodeToReallocate->PtrTableCapacity){
        return;
    }
    int newSize = (nodeToReallocate->PtrTableCapacity)*INCREASE_FACTOR;
    if(debuglog)printf("(re)Allocating %p with %d bytes. ", nodeToReallocate->childPtrTable,sizeof(mmUctNode*)*newSize);
    fflush(stdout);
    mmUctNode** tmp =(mmUctNode**)realloc(nodeToReallocate->childPtrTable,sizeof(mmUctNode*)*newSize);
    if(!tmp){
        puts("Re-allocation failed");
        free(nodeToReallocate->childPtrTable);
        dump();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    nodeToReallocate->childPtrTable=tmp;
    if(debuglog)printf(" Got %p\n",nodeToReallocate->childPtrTable);
    nodeToReallocate->PtrTableCapacity=newSize;
    tableReallocations++;
}
```

Comment: You're not handling the situation where realloc succeeds but returns a different address.

Comment: @tinman: what's wrong with `nodeToReallocate->childPtrTable=tmp;`?

Comment: @tinman Thats done on the line just below the `if(!tmp)` clause.

Comment: May it be because you are calling `exit` after freeing this node, but there are other nodes that are not freed and thus leaked?

Comment: @tinman, realloc handles that automatically -- `If the new size of the memory object would require movement of the object, the space for the previous instantiation of the object is freed.`

Comment: The cast on the `realloc()` call is, at best, redundant and it may hide an error (of failing to `#include <stdlib.h>`). Remove the cast and recompile.

Comment: @Michael: can't really say it's a false positive without a self-contained demonstration. The questioner says "I made sure I free the nodeToReallocate->childPtrTable at the end" but Valgrind disagrees, so who's more trustworthy? ;-)

Comment: If you are using `g++` or `gcc` compile with `-g` - this will add debug symbols so valgrind can show you numbers lines on which the problem is. Also try running valgrind with some additional parameters - I think `--leak-check=full` should be good.